# Is the Random Generator from Delphi the same calculation as C# if fed the same seed?

Tags: c#, delphi, random

I'm translating some Delphi code into c# code when I ran into this. I don't have an environment setup for Delphi so I can't test it myself.

Delphi:

```
RandSeed := var1;
Result := Random($FF);
```

c#:

```
Random RandSeed = new Random(var1);
Result = RandSeed.Next(255);
```

Would these put the same value in Result? If not, any ideas on a way to do so?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Delphi PRNG is a deterministic [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with 134775813 as **`a`** and 1 as **`c`**, and returning the high 32 bits for range-limited numbers. Here's an implementation in C# that returns the same values as Delphi:

```
using System;

class DelphiRandom
{
    int _seed;

    public DelphiRandom(int seed)
    {
        _seed = seed;
    }

    int GetNext() // note: returns negative numbers too
    {
        _seed = _seed * 0x08088405 + 1;
        return _seed;
    }

    public int Next(int maxValue)
    {
        ulong result = (ulong) (uint) GetNext() * (ulong) (uint) maxValue;
        return (int) (result >> 32);
    }
}

class App
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DelphiRandom r = new DelphiRandom(42);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            Console.WriteLine(r.Next(100));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Certainly not, because they use different RNGs. You could perhaps use a RNG from the Windows API, create your own RNG or use some RNG library to achieve this.

Another way to make sure your RNG creates the same numbers for a given seed would be to write a DLL and use it for both Delphi and C#.

By the way, if you want to code a RNG yourself, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators) is a good starting point to get the names of some usual generators. After you're done, you should run it through some [statistical test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) to make sure it's "random" enough for you.

Answer (score 3):

Just some results using Delphi 2009 and the first 10 of each seed:

```
Seed:   0, result:   0,   8, 219,  51,  69, 171,  81,  41,  94, 108
Seed:   1, result:   8, 219,  51,  69, 171,  81,  41,  94, 108,  20
Seed:   2, result:  16, 176, 138,  87,  17, 246,   1, 148, 122, 188
Seed:   3, result:  24, 132, 225, 105, 119, 156, 216, 202, 135, 100
Seed:   4, result:  32,  89,  57, 123, 221,  66, 176,   0, 149,  13
Seed:   5, result:  40,  45, 145, 141,  67, 231, 136,  54, 163, 180
Seed:   6, result:  48,   2, 232, 159, 169, 141,  96, 108, 176,  92
Seed:   7, result:  56, 213,  64, 177,  16,  51,  56, 161, 190,   5
Seed:   8, result:  64, 170, 151, 195, 118, 216,  16, 215, 203, 172
Seed:   9, result:  72, 127, 238, 213, 219, 126, 231,  14, 217,  84
Seed:  10, result:  80,  83,  70, 231,  66,  36, 191,  67, 231, 252
Seed:  11, result:  88,  40, 157, 248, 168, 201, 151, 121, 244, 164
Seed:  12, result:  96, 251, 244,  11,  14, 111, 111, 175,   3,  76
Seed:  13, result: 104, 208,  76,  29, 116,  21,  71, 228,  17, 244
Seed:  14, result: 112, 164, 163,  47, 218, 186,  31,  27,  30, 156
Seed:  15, result: 120, 121, 250,  65,  64,  96, 246,  81,  44,  69
Seed:  16, result: 128,  78,  83,  83, 166,   6, 206, 134,  57, 236
Seed:  17, result: 136,  34, 170, 101,  13, 171, 166, 188,  71, 148
Seed:  18, result: 144, 246,   2, 119, 114,  81, 126, 242,  85,  61
Seed:  19, result: 152, 202,  89, 137, 216, 246,  86,  40,  98, 228
Seed:  20, result: 160, 159, 176, 155,  63, 156,  46,  94, 112, 140
Seed:  21, result: 168, 115,   8, 173, 164,  66,   6, 148, 126,  53
Seed:  22, result: 176,  72,  95, 191,  11, 231, 221, 201, 139, 220
Seed:  23, result: 184,  29, 182, 209, 113, 141, 181,   0, 153, 132
Seed:  24, result: 192, 240,  14, 227, 214,  51, 141,  54, 166,  45
Seed:  25, result: 200, 197, 101, 245,  61, 216, 101, 107, 180, 212
```

I see a pattern ;-).

Comment: Is this from the C# or Delphi RNG?

Comment: Delphi, he has no delphi environment. But I corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Delphi 5 indeed gives the same. Tested it here, too. Guess that's why you should throw away the first random values for most RNGs.

Comment: Yup, or use a variable for the seed. For example (part of) the system time.

Answer (score 1):

For Java Developers

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.delphi;

/**
 *
 * @author ulmum
 * Using Code for C# from Barry Kelly http://stackoverflow.com/users/3712/barry-kelly
 */
class DelphiRandom {

    int _seed;

    public DelphiRandom(int seed) {
        _seed = seed;
    }

    int GetNext() // note: returns negative numbers too
    {
        _seed = _seed * 0x08088405 + 1;
        return _seed;
    }

    public int Next(int maxValue) {
        long result = (long) (int) GetNext() * (long) (int) maxValue;
        return ((int) (result >> 32) & 0xff); //Here Prevent Negative Numbers
    }
}

class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DelphiRandom r = new DelphiRandom(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            System.out.println(r.Next(256));
        }
    }
}
```